# "closure may outlive the current function" while used as a parameter

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to pass a function as a parameter and call it inside a thread. Here's the code that I'm trying to run:

```
use std::thread;

pub struct Image {
    pub data: Vec<u8>,
}

pub trait ImageHandler {
    fn get_image(&self) -> Option<Image>;
}

pub struct Window {
    pub id: usize,
}

impl ImageHandler for Window {
    fn get_image(&self) -> Option<Image> {
        None
    }
}

fn test(func: impl Fn() -> Option<Image> + Sync + Send + 'static) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let _image = func().unwrap();
    })
}

fn main() {
    let window = Window { id: 0 };
    test(&|| window.get_image());
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `window`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:30:11
   |
30 |     test(&|| window.get_image());
   |           ^^ ------ `window` is borrowed here
   |           |
   |           may outlive borrowed value `window`
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
  --> src/main.rs:30:5
   |
30 |     test(&|| window.get_image());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `window` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
30 |     test(&move || window.get_image());
   |           ^^^^^^^

error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:30:11
   |
30 |     test(&|| window.get_image());
   |     ------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |     |     |
   |     |     creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |     argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

I suppose `Fn` should be static for sending it to thread but when I change its lifetime to `'static`, it complains.
Also I don't know if it's possible to use `ImageHandler` as a parameter. I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: I don't know rust, but it looks like "borrows" is rust terminology for creating a _reference_ to a variable that is "owned" somewhere else—In this case, it's the variable, `window`, which is owned by your `main()` function. I guess that variable will cease to exist when `main()` returns, but you're passing a closure that "borrows" it into a new thread that will continue to exist _after_ `main()` has returned. That means the thread would have a reference to a non-existent variable. That's a Bad Thing in any programming language. Phimuemue's answer shows how to "move" the value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the closure can outlive the current thread, it should take ownership of the variables it needs:

```
fn main() {
    let window = Window { id: 0 };
    test(move || window.get_image());
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9cbf953b79e80e280156688d083f94fb has the playground.

However, as (I guess) this is only a toy example, this fix may or may not apply to your real use case. If it becomes more complicated you could try to convince the compiler that you know that the closure will not outlive the current thread (possibly using auxiliary crates) or resort to other techniques.